# Accessing Windows Scheduled Task using C#

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, credentials

How do I change the credentials used by a scheduled task using C#.NET?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using code, you can do it using 'SCHTASKS' command, run it using System.Diagnostic.Process.Start method with the parameters required. It's easy and not much effort required.

Answer (score 4):

Someone has written a task scheduler class library on [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx), it might be what your after...

**:)**

Answer (score 3):

You must call RegisterTaskDefintion for the task's definition with the new username and password to change just the password.

Code fragment

```
// Add COM-Reference to "TaskScheduler 1.1 Type Library" to the project
using TaskScheduler;

// code in function X

TaskSchedulerClass TaskClass = new TaskSchedulerClass();
TaskClass.Connect();

// access one task (or search for it or enumerate over all tasks)
IRegisteredTask lTask = null;
lTask = TaskClass.GetFolder("\\").GetTasks(0)[0];

// provide domain\\username and password (ask user for it, use encryption)
string lUsername = "TestDomain\\TestUsername"; // TestDomain can be the hostname for a local user
string lPassword = "xyzPassword";

RegisterTaskDefinition(lTask.Path, lTask.Definition, (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_UPDATE, lUsername, lPassword, lTask.Definition.Principal.LogonType, Type.Missing);
```

Original source for answer:
http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/discussions/215362

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this library](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx) for working with TaskSheduler. It's written in VB, but I referenced it easily and called it from C#.