# How to bring a system out of standby programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, shutdown

Is there a way to do it in c# or vb.net? I have to bring a system out of standby and play a notification sound if it is in standby mode, at specific time intervals. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373235(VS.85).aspx). IMHO this task will involve some heavy interop calls.

Comment: If it's possible at all from managed code. Some things just aren't.

Answer (score 5):

You can wake a computer from sleep with a scheduled task:

[image]

So the simplest option maybe to [create a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992549/accessing-windows-scheduled-task-using-c) to run at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the system is in standby you are somewhat limited and almost certainly going to be reliant on an external trigger and/or the capabilities of the system bios for the device.

The primary method that springs to mind is Wake-On-LAN, if the system has this capability then you could have a central 'server' firing off 'wake-up' packets to the device(s) at the desired interval and then the system would spring into life, what I'm not sure of is the ability to determine if the system was in standby with a simple call. One solution might be to have your service running on the target system and to grab the current time at a designated time interval, your app would then sleep for the time interval and when it next comes to retrieve the time, do a quick compare with the stored time to see if the elapsed interval matches the sleep time, if not then you have probably spent some time in standby.