# Remote scheduled task status

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, psexec

for my application I want to be monitoring the "Status" tab of specific scheduled task on a remote server and perform actions based on that status. ie, run a task if it is not already running, etc.

As of right now, I am launching cmd.exe as a process in C#, psexec'ing that machine's schtasks into a text file, reading that text file, and then I perform the corresponding action.

Are there better ways to do this process (get a specific status of a schtask) that do not involve 3rd party opens-source libs?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the native [`TaskService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM API:

```
//add reference to the 'Task Scheduler 1.1 Type Library'

using TaskScheduler;

//...

TaskSchedulerClass ts = new TaskSchedulerClass();
ts.Connect(remotehost, user, domain, password);
IRunningTaskCollection tasks = ts.GetRunningTasks(1);
foreach (IRunningTask task in tasks)
{
    Console.WriteLine(task.Name);
}
```

For some task on security and permissions see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382140(v=vs.85).aspx

Alternatively, if powershell is an option that might be easier depending on the version.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx

Also here:

[Accessing Windows Scheduled Task using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992549/accessing-windows-scheduled-task-using-c-sharp)