# C# Using WMI to Schedule a Task on a Remote Server

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-x64

I'm try to run a batch file on a remote, Windows 2008 server. I need to the file to run in an interactive fashion as it will open up numerous interactive programs. I can't install services on the remote server. I'm having difficulty trying to create a task on the remote server

Code:

```
string command = @"c:\test.bat > c:\tmp_dr.dat";
ConnectionOptions conO = new ConnectionOptions();
conO.Username = username;
conO.Password = password;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\10.12.62.205\root\cimv2", conO);
scope.Connect();

//Getting time
string serverTime = null;
SelectQuery timeQuery = new SelectQuery(@"select LocalDateTime from Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher timeQuerySearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(timeQuery);
foreach (ManagementObject mo in timeQuerySearcher.Get())
{
    serverTime = mo["LocalDateTime"].ToString();
}

//Adding 2 minutes to the time
string addTwoMinutes = (Convert.ToInt32(Strings.Mid(serverTime, 9, 4)) + 1).ToString();
if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Mid(serverTime, 9, 1).Equals("0"))//Check if hour is zero
{
    addTwoMinutes = "0" + addTwoMinutes;
}
serverTime = Strings.Replace(serverTime, (Strings.Mid(serverTime, 9, 4)), addTwoMinutes, 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text);

//running command
object[] cmdParams = { command, serverTime, false, null, null, true, 0};
ManagementClass serverCommand = new ManagementClass(scope, new ManagementPath("Win32_ScheduledJob"), null);
serverCommand.InvokeMethod("Create", cmdParams);
```

I am able to retrieve the time but this does not seem to create a task on the remote server. I'm very new to all of this so I'd appreciate any guidance on the matter that people may be able to provide. Thanks

ALSO: psexec is not possible.

SOLUTION FOUND:

The command variable was being sent to AT as a string[]. Dumb mistake.

Comment: You might find some of these helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992549/accessing-windows-scheduled-task-using-c-sharp  and even though this is VB: http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2004/08/Interfacing-the-Windows-Task-Scheduler.aspx  It still has some good stuff.

Comment: I was looking at that, I wasn't sure if it was still applicable to 2008 though. I'll give it a go; thanks for the information.